# A formal way to place the emphasis on myself

Tags: grammar, expressions, syntactic-analysis

I want the person to feel they can contact me directly but also give them the option to get in touch with other colleagues.  It is a big benefit to them to have the capacity to contact me directly.

Usually, I would say something like "my colleagues and I" but this time it needs to be less deferential and the emphasis need to be on me.

The below looks wrong.

> Please get in touch directly with me or my colleagues.

Does anyone know a formal way of putting the emphasis on me?

Comment: Why does "Please get in touch directly with me or my colleagues" look wrong to you?

Comment: @Julhasz it sounds juvenile to my ears.

Comment: Not sure why you think your sentence is juvenile - ? It’s perfectly fine English. My suggestion was meant to emphasize *you* as the preferred contact, but there’s nothing wrong with your original sentence.

Comment: It may be grammatically correct but lacks eloquence... to my ears at least.

Answer (score -1):

ORIGINAL ANSWER: How about: “Please get in touch directly with me (preferably) or my colleagues if I am unavailable”?

EDIT: now that I understand what the OP is asking about, I no longer think the change I suggested above is necessary. The original sentence is fine. Here is what I said in a comment below:

“Me and my friends” sounds juvenile when it’s used as a subject, because it shows that the speaker doesn’t know the difference between subject and object pronouns. As an object, though, it’s fine- “my friends and me” would usually be preferable but the reverse is not wrong. Likewise, “me or my colleagues” would sound juvenile as a subject but not as an object. The order of words here is fine (“me” first) because you want to emphasize “me” as the preferred contact. (To be clear, I am talking about your original sentence.)

"Please get in touch directly with me or my colleagues" is perfectly correct and "mature" English. Putting "me" first in the sentence (before "my colleagues") is sufficient if you want the person to feel free to contact you or else any of your colleagues if you're not available.

Comment: That sounds much better.

Comment: @SeanJ I don't see how this sounds better at all. Assuming you don't like your original sentence, all this does is add more verbiage. This version is less succinct, less formal, and more deferential. As far as I can tell, it doesn't address your question. But since you accepted it, I can only think you meant something different than what you actually asked for.

Comment: I disagree on the notion that it is less formal.  I would always opt for my friends and I but it doesn't suit.  Me and my friends is very informal and typical of a child, at least in my age bracket.  Adding verbiage formalises the statement.  I would prefer something that is succinct and not dressed up.  If you have a better answer....

Comment: “Me and my friends” sounds juvenile when it’s used as a subject, because it shows that the speaker doesn’t know the difference between subject and object pronouns. As an object, though, it’s fine- “my friends and me” would usually be preferable but the reverse is not wrong. Likewise, “me or my colleagues” would sound juvenile as a subject but not as an object. The order of words here is fine (“me” first) because you want to emphasize “me” as the preferred contact. (To be clear, I am talking about your original sentence.)

Comment: Please elaborate why you think this fits the questions. As it is phrased, it appears in the low-quality queue and is subject to deletion because it lacks explanation.

Comment: I'll edit my answer and include what I said in the above comment.

Comment: @SeanJ “Please get in touch with my colleagues or I” would, by many speakers, be considered **ungrammatical** and sound what many would call ‘uneducated’; it is certainly best avoided in formal contexts. There is nothing informal or childish about “me and my friends” – its only problem is the etiquette faux pas of not mentioning yourself last out of deference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet not in my part of the world.  I 100% disagree with you, perhaps you live in the US?  I am a native English speaker in Europe for reference.

Comment: @SeanJ So am I. Which part do you disagree on? The ungrammaticality of “with my colleagues and I” (which is traditional, though some linguists argue that a coordinated NP need not behave identically to a non-coordinated NP), or the level of formality of “me and my friends”?

Comment: In particular the later, `There is nothing informal or childish about “me and my friends”` but also the former.  I must have made a faux pas here because my question has been marked down without explanation and the only person decent enough to reply has been penalized for being helpful.  Can I suggest that if you have an answer that you please answer the question.

Comment: “With my colleagues and I” is an example of [hypercorrection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection). “(NP) and I” is taught as the “proper” way to refer to other people and oneself together. However, this only applies when “(NP) and I” is the subject, e.g. “My colleagues and I will get in touch with you”. Many people will assume that “Me and (NP)” and “(NP) and me” are therefore always wrong- but either of these is absolutely “correct”/“normal” English when used as an object, as in your original sentence- “Please get in touch with my colleagues or(and) me”.